# How can I set the timeline view on Espocrm?

Tags: fullcalendar, espocrm

I would like to display all the hours on the timeline by default as per the screenshot.
Now I have to move forward with the mouse wheel to view all the hour columns.
Currently it shows me the day divided into 6 columns, each column is made up of 4 hours.

Thanks

[image]

I tried to edit several .js but couldn't